# delphi write data with updateresources

Tags: delphi, resources

I try to write a string to an external exe file, but when i read the string via the other project i get an other string.
Example:
When i write "test123" then i read "test123Click".
When i write "test" then i read "test.".
When i write "name" then i read "name.".

I use this script to write:

```
 procedure WriteSettings(ServerFile: string; Settings: string);
    var
     ResourceHandle: THandle;
     pwServerFile: PWideChar;
    begin
     GetMem(pwServerFile, (Length(ServerFile) + 1) * 2);
     try
       StringToWideChar(ServerFile, pwServerFile, Length(ServerFile) * 2);
       ResourceHandle := BeginUpdateResourceW(pwServerFile, False);
       UpdateResourceW(ResourceHandle, MakeIntResourceW(10), 'SETTINGS', 0, @Settings[1], ByteLength(settings));
       EndUpdateResourceW(ResourceHandle, False);
     finally
       FreeMem(pwServerFile);
     end;
    end;
```

This is the script to read:

```
function LoadSettings: string;
var
  ResourceLocation: HRSRC;
  ResourceSize: dword;
  ResourceHandle: THandle;
  ResourcePointer: pointer;
begin
  ResourceLocation := FindResource(hInstance, 'SETTINGS', RT_RCDATA);
  ResourceSize := SizeofResource(hInstance, ResourceLocation);
  ResourceHandle := LoadResource(hInstance, ResourceLocation);
  ResourcePointer := LockResource(ResourceHandle);
  if ResourcePointer <> nil then
  begin
    SetLength(Result, ResourceSize - 1);
    CopyMemory(@Result[1], ResourcePointer, ResourceSize);
    FreeResource(ResourceHandle);
  end;
end;
```

What i am doing wrong?
I use everywhere a normal string, so not ansi and utf8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write a null terminator. Every time you call `UpdateResourceW` pass `(Length(str)+1)*SizeOf(str[1])` for the byte count parameter.

Also, `@Settings[1]` will fail for the empty string. I'd use `PWideChar()` instead. Like so:

```
UpdateResourceW(ResourceHandle, MakeIntResourceW(10), 'SETTINGS', 0, 
    PWideChar(Settings), (Length(Settings)+1)*SizeOf(Settings[1]));
```

Although all the explicit `W` suffixing is rather needless. You can write:

```
UpdateResource(ResourceHandle, MakeIntResource(10), 'SETTINGS', 0, 
    PChar(Settings), (Length(Settings)+1)*SizeOf(Settings[1]));
```

And the dynamic memory allocation is needless. You can write:

```
procedure WriteSettings(ServerFile: string; Settings: string);
var
  ResourceHandle: THandle;
begin
  ResourceHandle := BeginUpdateResource(PChar(ServerFile), False);
  UpdateResource(ResourceHandle, MakeIntResource(10), 'SETTINGS', 0, 
      PChar(Settings), (Length(Settings)+1)*SizeOf(Settings[1]));
  EndUpdateResource(ResourceHandle, False);
end;
```

And you really should include some error checking:

```
procedure WriteSettings(ServerFile: string; Settings: string);
var
  ResourceHandle: THandle;
begin
  ResourceHandle := BeginUpdateResource(PChar(ServerFile), False);
  Win32Check(ResourceHandle<>0);
  Win32Check(UpdateResource(ResourceHandle, MakeIntResource(10), 'SETTINGS', 0, 
      PChar(Settings), (Length(Settings)+1)*SizeOf(Settings[1])));
  Win32Check(EndUpdateResource(ResourceHandle, False));
end;
```